# Parsing Advanced XML File & Turning Information Into Class In C#

Tags: c#, xml

## What needs to be done

Currently I have 1 *Advanced* **XML** file that needs to be **parsed**. I need to iterate through the file and read each "Entity" tag individually. Altough the issue I come across is reading & iterating through the Stats and Slots. Also, the amount of Stat & Slot tags will vary depending on the Entity. (Yes I have researched this topic but I still can't find a way without creating errors as I need some more guidance. The other posts haven't had the exact fix I've hoped for...)

## XML File

```
<ROOT>
    <Entity Type="Clothing" Name="Light Robe" ID="0">
        <Armor>2</Armor>
        <Weight>1</Weight>
        <Usability>120</Usability>
        <Rarity>0.1</Rarity>
        <Stats>
            <Stat Type="Health">10</Stat>
        </Stats>
        <Slots>
            <Slot>Torso</Slot>
        </Slots>
    </Entity>
    <Entity Type="Clothing" Name="Medium Robe" ID="1">
        <Armor>4</Armor>
        <Weight>2</Weight>
        <Stats>
            <Stat Type="Health">15</Stat>
        </Stats>
        <Usability>120</Usability>
        <Rarity>0.1</Rarity>
        <Slots>
            <Slot>Torso</Slot>
        </Slots>
    </Entity>
    <Entity Type="Clothing" Name="Heavy Robe" ID="2">
        <Armor>6</Armor>
        <Weight>4</Weight>
        <Stats>
            <Stat Type="Health">25</Stat>
        </Stats>
        <Usability>120</Usability>
        <Rarity>0.1</Rarity>
        <Slots>
            <Slot>Torso</Slot>
        </Slots>
    </Entity>
</ROOT>
```

If anybody has any criticism of this post please say so as I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: Why do you consider this XML to be "advanced"?

Comment: @MichaelKay I meant to put in the advanced in qoutes haha. I don't really think it's advanced but on a relative scale for me it's 'advanced'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) for XML reading.

```
    // Load Document
    XDocument _doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\t\\My File2.txt");
    // Get all Entity elements and put them into a list.
    List<XElement> employees = _doc.XPathSelectElements("ROOT/Entity").ToList();

    // Next you can loop thru the list to check the Entity's elements
    foreach (var employee in employees)
    {
        // to get the armor element: 
        string armor = employee.Element("Armor").Value;
        // to get the rarity element:
        string rarity = employee.Element("Rarity").Value;
        // to get the Stat element:
        string stat = employee.Element("Stats").Element("Stat").Value;
        // to get the Slot element:
        string slot = employee.Element("Slots").Element("Slot").Value;
    }

    // To get one element specific by attribute use this (I check on attribute ID):
      XElement emp = _doc.XPathSelectElements("ROOT/Entity").FirstOrDefault(c => c.Attribute("ID").Value == "0");
    // Next you can extract information from this element just like in the foreach loop.
```